# Unable to login to Linux box running Xfce using LXDM login manager

Tags: xfce, lxde

I am running a Linux box with the `LXDM` login manager and Xfce as my desktop environment.

Every time I login, this is the screen I get: 
[image]

If I enter the right password, the system logs me in without any problems. But if I enter the wrong password, after a few seconds, this is what I get:
[image]

Because of this, I end up rebooting the whole machine so that I can get the input box to enter the correct password.

Could someone please tell me how I might solve this issue? Or at least point me in the right direction?

Comment: You should be able to restart the X server and log in again by hitting Ctrl Alt Backspace unless you have disabled it. You can also drop to a tty (Ctrl+Alt_F2), login there and run `service lxdm restart`.

Comment: It looks like an `LXDM` bug. Did you try reporting it upstream? Also, did you try with some other lightweight DM, something like `lightdm`?